# Merge datatable (Row not found)

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

i have sql1 insert into dt1, and sql2 insert into dt2.

Im trying to merge these 2 datatables. Ive try to run them separately and it work only if i try to merge error occur. Is there any way to merge? I dont want to use join

dt1

```
|column1|col2|col3|
```

dt2

```
|col4|col5|col6|
```

dt2 required infomation from sql1+sql3

ive tried dt1.Merge(dt2)

I was hoping to get end output like:

```
|col1|col2|col3||col4|col5|col6|
```

Comment: _"... I dont want to use join..."_ The question is why?

Comment: Because for col4, the value i need to fetch from another sql and run FOR loop. i would like to paste code here, but is too long. stakover flow wont allow it @Sami

Comment: Is there any relationship between the 2 tables? How do you want to match the rows in the first table to the second table?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the database?

```
select sql1.col1, sql1.col2, sql1.col3, sql2.col4, sql2.col5, sql2.col6
from sql1 cross join
     sql2;
```

Comment: I cant use join Because for col4, the value i need to fetch from another sql and run FOR loop